Data mutations not updating the UI instantly because the page is not re-rendering
Building an app with NextJS 14 App Router. Part of the app is a facebook-like thread where users can post messages. The problem I encounter is the UI not re-rendering/updating after client-side data mutations like clicking 'like' buttons or adding a comment. It all works fine in the main thread where you can see all the posts by all users. However, when selecting posts by user, navigating to the postsbyuser page, features like clicking a like button or adding a comment only works once, after that only on page refresh, the UI is not instantly updated/refreshed.
The data is mutated as expected in the database but not rendered on the UI.
I tried router refresh which only works on the /api/posts/ route, revalidatePath didn't solve the problem either. Optimistic updates could be the solution but I want to avoid that.
I guess state is not being re-initialized or revalidated properly after data mutations are send to the server.
Api folder structure

Posts by user route
export const GET = async (request, {params}) => {
  try {
    await connectDB();

    const {postId} = params;

     if (!postId) {
       return null;
     }

    const posts = await Post.aggregate([
      { $match: { user: ObjectId.createFromHexString(postId) } }, 
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "comments", 
          localField: "_id", 
          foreignField: "postId", 
          as: "comments", 
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "likes", 
          localField: "_id", 
          foreignField: "postId", 
          as: "likes", 
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: { createdAt: -1 }, 
      },
    ]);
              
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({posts}), { status: 200 });
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

Post like route
export const POST = async (request, { params }) => {
  await connectDB();

  const { postId } = params;
  const session = await getSessionUser()

  if (!session) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({message: "Unauthorized"}), { status: 401 });
  }

  const userId = session.user.id;

  try {

    const liked = await Like.findOne({ postId, userId });
       if(liked){
             const deletedLike = await Like.findOneAndDelete({ postId, userId });
       if(deletedLike){
           await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(postId, { $inc: { likesCount: -1 } });
       }
      }

     if(!liked){
            const like = await Like.create({ userId, postId });
            await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(postId, { $inc: { likesCount: 1 } });
     }
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(liked), { status: 201 });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response({message:error.message}, { status: 500 });
  }
};

Comment like route
export const POST = async (request, { params }) => {
  
  await connectDB();

  const { commentId } = params;
  const session = await getSessionUser();

  const postId = commentId   // You need postId because in the Like Schema there is no commentId

  if (!session) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Unauthorized" }), {
      status: 401,
    });
  }

  const userId = session.user.id;

  try {
    const liked = await Like.findOne({ postId, userId });
    if (liked) {
      const deletedLike = await Like.findOneAndDelete({ postId, userId });
      if (deletedLike) {
        await Comment.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:postId}, {$inc: { likesCount: -1 }});
      }
    }

    if (!liked) {
      const like = await Like.create({ userId, postId });
    
       if(like){
           await Comment.findByIdAndUpdate(postId, { $inc: { likesCount: 1 }});
       }
    }

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(liked), { status: 201 });
   
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response({ message: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
   
};

Comment like button
const CommentLikeButton = ({com, initialLikesCount }) => {

      const router = useRouter();

     const toggleLike = async (commentId) => {

       console.log("Id:", commentId);

       try {
         const res = await fetch(`/api/posts/comments/${commentId}/like`, {
           method: "POST",
           headers: {
             "Content-Type": "application/json",
           },
           body: JSON.stringify({ commentId }),
         });

         if (!res.ok) {
           alert("Login first!");
         }
       } catch (error) {
         console.error("Error toggling like:", error);
       }
       router.refresh();
     };
}

